# Write file to SD card root directory with ionic/cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I need to write file to root directory of sd-card.
I use [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) function from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin).
And get something like this:

```
[{
     "path": "/storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files",
     "filePath": "file:///storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files",
     "canWrite": true,
     "freeSpace": 16254009344,
     "type": "application"
 }, {
     "path": "/storage/4975-1401",
     "filePath": "file:///storage/4975-1401",
     "canWrite": false,
     "freeSpace": 16254009344,
      "type": "root"
}]
```

So, I can't write to `file:///storage/4975-1401`, because `"canWrite": false`
I've add

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
```

to `config.xml` and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml`, but no results, when I try write file to root directory, I get error `CODE 5 ENCODING_ERR`

Writing to `/storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files` is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 4.4 Kitkat, non-system apps have read-only permission to secondary storage volumes (i.e. removable SD cards) outside of their application sandbox area (`/Android/data/[package-id]/`). [See here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150227000746/https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/) for a more detailed explanation.

So the `getExternalSdCardDetails()` function is correctly informing you that you can write to the application sandbox directory `/storage/4975-1401/Android/data/cordova.plugins.diagnostic.example/files` but not to the root directory `/storage/4975-1401/`.

There is no way around this on Android 4.4 and above unless the device is rooted.